# How to pass data to child component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to vue.js and I try to pass a value to the child component.

HTML

```
<div id="example">
   <my-component v-bind:data="parentData"></my-component>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: '<div>Parent component with data: {{ data.value }}!<div is="my-component-child" v-bind:data="childData"></div></div>'
});

Vue.component('my-component-child', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: '<div>Child component with data: {{ data.value }} </div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    parentData: {
      value: 'hello parent!'
    },
    childData: {
      value: 'hello child!'
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9osont9/2/

And I've got this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "childData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in )
>
> [Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
>   (found in )
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Notice that `data` is bad name for property, because in Vue-component `data` means data-model, it is kind of reserved word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

```
<my-component v-bind:data="parentData"></my-component>
```

you are passing only the `parentData` to your parent component and `childData` gets out of scope.

You need to nest your `childData` in your `parentData`:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data: {
        parentData: {
            value: 'hello parent!',
            childData: {
                value: 'hello child!'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and pass it to your child like this:

```
<div is="my-component-child" v-bind:data="data.childData">
```